# Define method without using prototype

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use the statement as shown below to define a method without the use of `prototype`?

```
Person.sayHello = function () {...}
```

On this example

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};

var person1 = new Person("Alice");
var person2 = new Person("Bob");
```

Comment: That isn't how the language works. Why would you want or need to do this?

Comment: Just wonder the difference between these two ^_^

Comment: I don't know. Did it work when you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no.

```
Person.sayHello = function () {...};
```

This line will add a function called "sayHello" to the Person class itself rather than to instances of the Person class.  So, it can only be invoked by

```
Person.sayHello();
```

rather than by

```
var matt = new Person('Matt');
matt.sayHello();
// sayHello is not defined on matt
```

If you are familiar with Java or C#, adding a method to Person in this way is like creating a static method.

However, we can add a method to instances without adding a method to the prototype.

**Method 1: Create the "sayHello" function in the constructor of Person**

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;

  this.sayHello = sayHello() {...};
};
```

This method has the disadvantage that a new function is created for every instance of Person.  That is,

```
var frank = new Person('Frank');
var matt = new Person('Matt');
// frank.sayHello != matt.sayHello;
```

Thus, this method can be hard on memory.  However, it does allow for encapsulation (e.g. private state) via closures.  In the following sample, it is impossible to modify the "count" variable outside of the Person class without calling the "sayHello" function.

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;

  this.sayHello = sayHello() {
    count++;
    console.log("Hello has been said " + count + "times".
  };

  var count = 0;
};
```

**Method 2: Create the "sayHello" function outside the constructor of Person and assign it within the constructor of Person**

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;

  this.sayHello = sayHello;
};

function sayHello() {...}
```

This method has the advantage of lower memory usage; there is only one instance of the sayHello function, and it is shared across instances of Person.  That is,

```
var frank = new Person('Frank');
var matt = new Person('Matt');
// frank.sayHello == matt.sayHello;
```

This makes it similar to the prototype method.  However, the assignment of the function to each instance still consumes more memory than the prototype method where the function is only assigned to the prototype object.

However, like the prototype method, this method does not allow for private state.  All state must be accessed through public state exposed via the `this` keyword.

---

**Update**: Clarification of the difference in memory usage between method 1 and method 2.

Method 1 is like this:

```
var function1 = function() { console.log('Hello'); };
var function2 = function() { console.log('Hello'); };
```

The functions have the same behavior, but are not equal.  JavaScript doesn't know they are functionally similar, so it creates two functions in memory to represent them.

Method 2 is like this:

```
var sayHello = function() { console.log('Hello'); };
var function1 = sayHello;
var function2 = sayHello;
```

Now function1 and function2 are actually the same function because they both simply hold a reference to sayHello.

---

**Update**: Example usage of a module pattern to avoid adding "sayHello" to the global scope in method 2.

This module defines the Person class in a module defined by an anonymous closure (a self executing function) and exports it to the global scope.  Because "sayHello" is defined in the closure of the module and is not exported, it is not added to the global scope.

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;

      this.sayHello = sayHello;
    };

    function sayHello() {...}

    return Person;
}());
```

Comment: Have some difficulty with understanding the: there is only one instance of the sayHello function, and it is shared across instances of Person.     I thought it's no different with method one except the method two has no access the private variable

Comment: So method 1 is like this:

    var function1 = function() { console.log('Hello'); };
    var function2 = function() { console.log('Hello'); };

The functions have the same behavior, but are not equal.  JavaScript doesn't know they are functionally similar, so it creates two functions in memory to represent them.

Method 2 is like this:

    var sayHello = function() { console.log('Hello'); };
    var function1 = sayHello;
    var function2 = sayHello;

function1 and function2 are now the same function because they both simply hold a reference to sayHello.

Comment: sorry, what do y mean?

Comment: Added clarification to answer because there is better formatting in answers than in comments. :)

Comment: Cool, but will it create another global functions, which is not a good practice.

Comment: Very true, but that can be avoided by using a module pattern, like those described in this [utterly fantastic article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).  Again, I updated the answer for better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you come from traditional OO background, it might help to think about this as effectively behaving like a public static property on a class.

As jsdeveloper said in the above comment. Functions are just objects that can be executed. You can add properties to them just like any other object. This technique is actually used in practice for patterns like memoization or currying.

In your case `sayHello` can accessed anywhere the Person function can be accessed.  It's not really related to inheritance/prototype since it doesn't have to do with resolving properties by traversing the prototype chain, but it is another way to make data accessible.

I'm sure it varies based on the developer, but I often put pure functions which don't reference `this` as static methods as you have done since they are easier to test and make the intention clear to other developers

Answer (score -1):

It would be weird, but if you really need to do it that way, you can assign the function to its own prototype once, then add all of the functions to the main function.

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
};
Person.prototype = Person;

Person.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can but the sayhello function will not be able to access any of the object properties (ie this.myvar) and you can only call it like a static method:

```
Person.sayhello()
```

(and not mypersonobject.sayhello).

When you extend the prototype, the sayhello function is available to all Person objects created using the 'new' keyword in the usual fashion.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsheridan390/kL7arrqs/

Comment: but I add the sayHello function on the person, not the specific object, the new created object should inherit the function defined on the person. where I am missing?Thanks

Comment: You can assign properties to a function variable but that doesnt mean that they will be available in constructed objects. As far as i know only the prototype functions get copied when you create a new object using 'new Person()'.

Comment: So do y know what it mean to do when we  use like: Person.sayHello=...? Thanks

Comment: Every function is an object and you can assign properties to objects, so therefore you can assign properties to functions. Person.sayhello is assigning the sayhello property to the Person function object.

Comment: I know that. So we can assign it to the constructor variable but we cannot do anything in this case